# Ionic 3 - ion-select - styling help - icon and lines

Tags: select, ionic-framework, dropdown, ionic3

After trying to implement a specific select design (see previous help asked on another thread: [Ionic 3 - Dropdown Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279554/ionic-3-dropdown-select)) 
I have settled to try and work with the ion-select that ionic provides.

This is what I have so far:
[Current Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3aZ9.png)

Does anyone know how to remove:
- the lines under each option
- the radio icons

And how to add a sub-heading inside the select dropdown like this, where "My Filters" is the sub-heading:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puqyn.png)

I have tried no-lines with no luck and tried changing the mode for the popovers to remove the radio icons and also no luck. Any help would be great.

My code so far:

```
    <ion-grid *ngIf="toggled">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-4>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Filter</ion-label>
        <ion-select interface="popover">
          <ion-option>Inbox</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Today</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Next 7 Days</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Overdue</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Watching</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Favourites</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Tasks assigned to</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Tasks I've assigned</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-4>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Due Date</ion-label>
        <ion-select interface="popover">
          <ion-option>Priority</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Status</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-4>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Order</ion-label>
        <ion-select interface="popover">
          <ion-option>Descending</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="20">Ascending</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: @gaurang

no not with the ion-select option.

i ended up creating it with ion-list and the having the whole section as     `position: relative;
display: inline-block;`
to allow the content to drop down on click

Answer (score 1):

didn't end up finding a solution. had to use different approach with CSS as below example of one of the dropdowns:

```
<ion-col col-4 text-center>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span class="flex-content">
      <button ion-button icon-only clear (click)="toggleFilter()" *ngIf="!toggledFilter || toggledFilter" class="filter-down">
        <!-- if filterCriteria is false (not present) then present 'Filter' -->
        <p class="filter-text">{{filterCriteria || 'Filter'}}</p>
        <!-- icons change based on down or up if the drop down is open -->
        <ion-icon [name]="!toggledFilter ? 'ios-arrow-down' : 'ios-arrow-up'" class="expand-icon"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </span>
    <ion-list no-lines class="dropdown-content" *ngIf="toggledFilter">
      <button ion-item (click)="filterCriteria = 'Inbox'; openFilterPage(pages[0])" class="filter-text background-text">Inbox</button>
      <button ion-item (click)="filterCriteria = 'Today'; openFilterPage(pages[1])" class="filter-text background-text">Today</button>
      <button ion-item (click)="filterCriteria = 'Next 7 days'; openFilterPage(pages[2])" class="filter-text background-text">Next 7 days</button>
      <button ion-item (click)="filterCriteria = 'Overdue'; openFilterPage(pages[3])" class="filter-text background-text">Overdue</button>
      <button ion-item (click)="filterCriteria = 'Watching'; openFilterPage(pages[4])" class="filter-text background-text">Watching</button>
      <button ion-item (click)="filterCriteria = 'Favourites'; openFilterPage(pages[5])" class="filter-text background-text">Favourites</button>
      <p class="dropdown-heading">My Filters</p>
      <button ion-item (click)="filterCriteria = 'Tasks assigned to'; closeFilter()" class="filter-text background-text">Tasks assigned to</button>
      <button ion-item (click)="filterCriteria = 'Tasks I\\'ve assigned'; closeFilter()" class="filter-text background-text">Tasks assigned by me</button>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-col>
```

and the CSS for it:

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 140px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 10px 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
  }

  .dropdown-heading {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: map-get($theme-color, sub-text);
    font-size: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DFE0E3;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-align: left;
  }
```

hope this helps in any way to get it slightly as wanted